# 2022 NDVI Data Not Available On Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, ndvi

I'm trying to find the most recent possible NDVI data from Google Earth Engine. This is the code I'm using:

```
// Coordinates for East Pine
var Cent = ee.Geometry.Point([-121.187547,55.689782]);

// Center Map on East Pine
Map.centerObject(Cent, 10);

// Import the Landsat 8 TOA image collection.
// Filter out images with cloud covdf > 10%
var Collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA').filter(ee.Filter.date('2022-01-01', '2022-12-01'));

// Get the number of images.
var count = Collection.size();
print('Count: ', count);

// Define NDVI Function
var addNDVI_Landsat = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

// Apply Function to all Images
var withNDVI_Landsat = Collection.map(addNDVI_Landsat);

// Make a "greenest" pixel composite.
var greenest = withNDVI_Landsat.qualityMosaic('NDVI');
var ndvi = greenest.select('NDVI')

// Define Color Scheme for Visualization
var ndviParams = {min: -.5, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};

// Display the result.
Map.addLayer(ndvi, ndviParams, 'Greenest pixel composite');

// // Export to Google drive
// Export.image.toDrive({
//   image: ndvi,
//   description: 'NDVI_2022',
//   scale: 30,
//   region: Boundary
// });
```

Running this code for any time in 2022 gives me nothing (Count = 16 as opposed to 90000+ in prior years), so I just wanted to make sure there weren't errors in my code or a different way to get the 2022 NDVI data before I proceeded.

Answer (score 2):

The Code Editor should be telling you that [`LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C01_T1_TOA) is deprecated. It has no new data for 2022 except for a couple days of January.

Its replacement is [`LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_TOA) in Landsat Collection 2, with data that's current to just a few days ago.

Comment: I always assumed `LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_RT_TOA` was the replacement of `LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT`, and `LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_TOA` was the replacement of `LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA`. Can you please clarify this a bit?

Comment: @DanielWiell Thanks for asking! You're right that the replacement should be `LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA`, not `LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_RT_TOA`. I've updated my answer, and the data catalog maintainers have been informed of the error too. (In the second part of your answer, `LE07` is Landsat 7, not 8, though.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Kevin. And sure, 8 not 7 :-)

Comment: @KevinReid do you need to perform cloud masking when using LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA

Comment: @DanielWiell do you need to perform cloud masking when using LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA

Comment: @N_LLC Commenting on answers is not a good way to ask questions. It won't be seen by very many people, there isn't room to give details (you'll need to say more about your purpose), and I don't have an answer for you. Please [post a proper question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).